# Scrape data from ActiveX Component

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, activex

With C#, is it possible to basically take in an activex object and get the data out of it? I have a call queue monitor thats an activex object, and I want to implement an alert system for my team, but I cant figure out how to get the data out of the ActiveX component.

Comment: Try using a screen reader, the kind that people with vision impairment use.  If it talks back then you've got a shot at it by using an automation library.  If not, fuggedaboudid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component doesn't provide a specific way to do it, then probably not easily. If the data is in controls on the screen (like in a window somewhere) then you can possibly use win32 functionality (FindWindow, GetWindowText, so pInvoke) to locate the controls that have the data. You'd need to use Spy++ to find the controls in the window and determine their Class Name and Window Name to do the FindWindow.

Here's one example from SO:
[Capturing data from a window in a closed-source third-party Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551705/capturing-data-from-a-window-in-a-closed-source-third-party-win32-application)

Comment: I was able to find a way to pull the queue data from outside the activex object. But from what I saw from your answer, it would have worked. Thank you!